# encoding/decoding textarea value using rawurlencode/rawurldecode

Tags: php, textarea, urldecode

When encoding newline of textarea before storing into mysql using PHP with `rawurlencode` function encodes newline as `%0D%0A`.

For Example:
textarea text entered by user:

```
a
b
```

encoding using rawurlencode and store into database will store value as `a%0D%0Ab`

When retrieving from database and decoding using `rawurldecode` does not work and code gives error. How to overcome this situation and what is the best way to store and retrieve and display textarea values.

Comment: is there a reason to use rawlurlencode for huge data like textarea ? should not it using POST method ?

Comment: I am using rawurlencode to encode all symbols before storing into the database, not for POST

Answer (score 1):

can you first encode this textarea string using `base64_encode` and then perform a `base64_decode` on the same, if the above does not work for you.

If the textarea does not contain URLs, you should rather use `base64_encode` then `rawurlencode` and then store as normal.

Comment: base64_encode is working good so far but base64_decode('YQ0KYg==') returned "a b" instead of showing a and b in two lines. ('YQ0KYg==' is encoded value of textarea having a and b in two lines)

Comment: hey ZHS, I tried running through this myself, as I was sure of what I am saying. `YQ0KYg==` is the encoded value for the required string (a and b in two separate lines). If however, you are having troubles showing that into two lines, use this on the decoded value, e.g. `str_replace(PHP_EOL,'\n',base64_decode('YQ0KYg=='));`, which will give `a\nb` where `\n` is our newline character. You can always dump the variables using `var_dump` function.

Comment: Also, if this is a user input textarea, ensure that you are escaping the data before storing it in database, e.g. for mysql, you can use: `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Another problem, base64_encode() add '+' sign in encoded string which crashes my application. Do you know which characters does it use while encoding? I have seen + and =

Comment: Please, use `strtr(base64_encode($string), '+/=', '-_,');` and `base64_decode(strtr($encoded, '-_,', '+/='));` - this will take care of these symbols.. or use something in the third argument of `strtr` which does not crash your application.

Answer (score 1):

You simply should not use rawurlencode for *escaping data for your database*.

Each target format has it's own escaping method which in general terms makes sure it is stored/display/transferred safely from one place to another, and it doesn't need *decoding* at the other end.

For instance:

- displaying text in HTML, use htmlentities or htmlspecialchars
- storing in database, use mysqli_real_escape_string, pg_escape_string, etc...
- transferring variablename, use urlencode
- transferring variablecontent, use rawurlencode
- etc...

You should notice that decoding these things is often done by the browser/database. So no data is actually stored escaped. And decoding doesn't need te be done by your code.

The problem is probably because you escape a sequence with rawurlencode, but your database expected the escaped format for the specific brand of database. And de-escaped it using that assumption, which was wrong, which messed up your string.

Conclusion: find out what brand database you are using, look up the specific escape function for that database, and use the proper escaping function on *all* your content "transferral".

---

P.S.: some definition may not be correct, please comment on that. I wanted to make the idea stick but am probably not using all the right terms.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is very uncommon to run textarea through urlencode()
urlencode was not designed for this purpose.

Second, if you still want to do this, then maybe the problem comes from database. First you need to tell us what database you using and what TYPE you using for storing this data: do you store it as TEXT or as BINARY data? Have you setup the correct charset in database?